# Shader mod in 1.8 with without black chests, signs, mobs, and player armor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I installed the ShadersMod-v2.4.2mc1.8 from http://minecraftsix.com/glsl-shaders-mod 
The 5/12/14 update must have fixed player skins, armors, and signs. However single chests are still black. This is very very very bad if I am planning on playing hunger games. As I can't find chests if they are black.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant but please install from the link that author provided. http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1286604-shaders-mod-updated-by-karyonix?comment=9415

Comment: Known issue
- Chunks outside of view have no shadow. There is sunlight in cave. 
**- Player/animal/mob model may become darken or black or invisible. sign and chest too.**
- Player/animal/mob does not flash red when hurt. 
- Bed has wrong entityData and has wave.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall it and it is supposed to fix it! It worked for me at least